# PHP - How to access other variable from other file?

Tags: php, variables, get

I have 2 php files : index.php and search_server.php.
I need to access $pilihdomain from index.php, then use that in search_server.php, on this lines `$resp = $uclassify->classify($tweet['text'], $pilihdomain, 'herlambangp');`

Last day, i use require ang global variable, but it seems wrong.
thanks in advance.

//index.php

```
<head>
    <title>Twitter Search</title>
    <link href="search_client.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="tweet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="search_client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search_box">
    <h1>Twitter Search</h1>
    <input name="search_terms" autofocus="autofocus"/>      
<?php 
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbname = "skripsi";
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namaklasifier");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $clsfr = $row['username'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namaklasifier");
        echo '<select name="cmake" autofocus width="10">';
        echo '<option value="0">-Pilih Domain Klasifikasi-</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<option ' . ($clsfr==$row['username']) . ' value="'.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
?>
    <?php
$pilihdomain=$_POST['cmake'];
    ?>
```

//search_server.php

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {

    // Remove any hack attempts from input data
    $search_terms = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']).' -smartfrencare -siapkan -klaim';

    // Get the application OAuth tokens
    require 'app_tokens.php';
    require_once("uClassify.php");
    $uclassify = new uClassify();
    // Set these values here
    $uclassify->setReadApiKey('8DvvfxwKPdvjgRSrtsTSOawmQ0');
    $uclassify->setWriteApiKey('v4Us59yQFhf9Z0nGrQsrTtzBI5k');
//   global $nilainet;
//   global $nilaineg;
//   global $nilaipos;

    // Create an OAuth connection
    require 'tmhOAuth.php';

    $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
      'consumer_key'    => $consumer_key,
      'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
      'user_token'      => $user_token,
      'user_secret'     => $user_secret
    ));

    // Request the most recent 100 matching tweets
    $http_code = $connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/search/tweets'), 
            array('q' => $search_terms,
                'count' => 50,
                'lang' => 'in',
                'locale' => 'jakarta',
                'type' => 'recent'));

    // Search was successful
    if ($http_code == 200) {

        // Extract the tweets from the API response
        $response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
        $tweet_data = $response['statuses']; 

        // Load the template for tweet display
        $tweet_template= file_get_contents('tweet_template.html');

        // Load the library of tweet display functions
        require 'display_lib.php';  

        // Create a stream of formatted tweets as HTML
        $tweet_stream = '';
        foreach($tweet_data as $tweet) {

            // Ignore any retweets
            if (isset($tweet['retweeted_status'])) {
                continue;
            }
            // Get a fresh copy of the tweet template
            $tweet_html = $tweet_template;


            $resp = $uclassify->classify($tweet['text'], $pilihdomain, 'herlambangp');              
            $value = print_r($resp,true) ;          
            // Insert this tweet into the html
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[screen_name]',$tweet['user']['screen_name'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[name]', $tweet['user']['name'],$tweet_html);        
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[profile_image_url]',$tweet['user']['profile_image_url'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_id]', $tweet['id'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_text]',linkify($tweet['text']),$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_class]',$value,$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[created_at]',twitter_time($tweet['created_at']),$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[retweet_count]',$tweet['retweet_count'],$tweet_html);           

            // Add the HTML for this tweet to the stream
            $tweet_stream .= $tweet_html;
        }

        // Pass the tweets HTML back to the Ajax request
        print $tweet_stream;

    // Handle errors from API request
    } else {
        if ($http_code == 429) {
            print 'Error: Twitter API rate limit reached';
        } else {
            print 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that search';
        }
    }

} else {
    //not implement anything
}   

?>
```

Comment: Use of the `MySQL` functions is deprecated, you can use `MySQLi` or (even better IMO) `PDO` functions instead. Also, try to separate your PHP logic from your HTML. (Google: `separation of concerns`)

Comment: [Your code has an XSS vulnerability.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: Hi @Luttekes, which MySql command that i have to change to MySQLi? is that all?any example for my case?thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you edit your question. I flagged it...

Comment: Please do not try to edit your question and add garbage data thinking that others won't see your question! Your edits are clearly listed here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17055709/revisions

Answer (score 2):

You should have an external "config" or "settings" file that contains variables that you require globally in your site.  Then, include that external file in all pages that need those configuration settings.

In addition to pilihdomain, I put your db settings in this file for you, because you really should make those shared settings rather than redefining them in every script that needs them.

**settings.php**

```
<?php
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbname = "skripsi";
$pilihdomain = isset($_POST['cmake']) ? $_POST['cmake'] : '';
```

**index.php**

```
<?php require_once('settings.php'); ?>
<head>
    <title>Twitter Search</title>
    <link href="search_client.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="tweet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="search_client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search_box">
    <h1>Twitter Search</h1>
    <input name="search_terms" autofocus="autofocus"/>      
<?php 
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$db);
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namaklasifier");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $clsfr = $row['username'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namaklasifier");
        echo '<select name="cmake" autofocus width="10">';
        echo '<option value="0">-Pilih Domain Klasifikasi-</option>';
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
            echo '<option ' . ($clsfr==$row['username']) . ' value="'.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>'; 
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
?>
```

**search_server.php**

```
<?php require_once('settings.php'); ?>
<?php 
if (!empty($_GET['q'])) {

    // Remove any hack attempts from input data
    $search_terms = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']).' -smartfrencare -siapkan -klaim';

    // Get the application OAuth tokens
    require 'app_tokens.php';
    require_once("uClassify.php");
    $uclassify = new uClassify();
    // Set these values here
    $uclassify->setReadApiKey('8DvvfxwKPdvjgRSrtsTSOawmQ0');
    $uclassify->setWriteApiKey('v4Us59yQFhf9Z0nGrQsrTtzBI5k');
//   global $nilainet;
//   global $nilaineg;
//   global $nilaipos;

    // Create an OAuth connection
    require 'tmhOAuth.php';

    $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
      'consumer_key'    => $consumer_key,
      'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
      'user_token'      => $user_token,
      'user_secret'     => $user_secret
    ));

    // Request the most recent 100 matching tweets
    $http_code = $connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/search/tweets'), 
            array('q' => $search_terms,
                'count' => 50,
                'lang' => 'in',
                'locale' => 'jakarta',
                'type' => 'recent'));

    // Search was successful
    if ($http_code == 200) {

        // Extract the tweets from the API response
        $response = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);
        $tweet_data = $response['statuses']; 

        // Load the template for tweet display
        $tweet_template= file_get_contents('tweet_template.html');

        // Load the library of tweet display functions
        require 'display_lib.php';  

        // Create a stream of formatted tweets as HTML
        $tweet_stream = '';
        foreach($tweet_data as $tweet) {

            // Ignore any retweets
            if (isset($tweet['retweeted_status'])) {
                continue;
            }
            // Get a fresh copy of the tweet template
            $tweet_html = $tweet_template;


            $resp = $uclassify->classify($tweet['text'], $pilihdomain, 'herlambangp');              
            $value = print_r($resp,true) ;          
            // Insert this tweet into the html
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[screen_name]',$tweet['user']['screen_name'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[name]', $tweet['user']['name'],$tweet_html);        
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[profile_image_url]',$tweet['user']['profile_image_url'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_id]', $tweet['id'],$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_text]',linkify($tweet['text']),$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[tweet_class]',$value,$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[created_at]',twitter_time($tweet['created_at']),$tweet_html);
            $tweet_html = str_replace('[retweet_count]',$tweet['retweet_count'],$tweet_html);           

            // Add the HTML for this tweet to the stream
            $tweet_stream .= $tweet_html;
        }

        // Pass the tweets HTML back to the Ajax request
        print $tweet_stream;

    // Handle errors from API request
    } else {
        if ($http_code == 429) {
            print 'Error: Twitter API rate limit reached';
        } else {
            print 'Error: Twitter was not able to process that search';
        }
    }

} else {
    //not implement anything
}   

?>
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, i will try your suggest asap. thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Steven, i've try the code, but $pilihdomain havent access yet, this is the error msg "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'uClassifyException' with message 'How should the text be classified? No ClassiferName seems to be specified!' in C:\xampp\htdocs\kejar\code\uClassify.php:107 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\kejar\code\search_server.php(62): uClassify->classify(',,,lah myn,,,"@...', NULL, 'herlambangp') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\kejar\code\uClassify.php on line 107"

Comment: @herlambangpermadi - That error is likely due to there being no post data to set `$pilihdomain.`.  I modified my answer above to set `$pilihdomain` to an empty string ('') if `$_POST['cmake']` is not set.

Comment: Hi @Steven, thanks for the response. is there someting missed in settings.php? i find "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' " message, i dont understand using "?" in php yet. thanks steven.

Comment: Edited again.  I had an extra semicolon in there.

Comment: i think it still not get $pilihdomain. Hi, @Steven i have edited your answer. if i'm using form i can access $pilihdomain. but because it is an js, form submit processing just like a flash.

Answer (score -2):

Use a session variable.
They're very easy to set up and them you can use them across pages.

Comment: Hi, is there any example using session in my problem case?

Comment: There's quite a lot of code in your example so I'm going to avoid giving an example for your code. However this article should explain everything you need to know about session variables: http://w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp .as I said though, these are very easy to set up, and its worth understanding how they work rather than me just writing  the solution. Teach a man to fish and all that.